# Why is this python 3 statement using a bitwise or instead of an "or"?

Tags: python, bitwise-operators, bitwise-xor

This python code below I found as part of a [problem statement over here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/divide-two-integers-without-using-multiplication-division-mod-operator/):

*Divide two integers without using multiplication, division and mod operator
Given a two integers say a and b. Find the quotient after dividing a by b without using multiplication, division and mod operator.*

```
sign = (-1 if((dividend < 0) ^  
                  (divisor < 0)) else 1);
```

I notice the code doesn't work if you don't have bitwise or operator. Why do you need a "bitwise or" instead of a logical "or" operator?

Comment: ^ is the XOR operator, not the OR operator.

Comment: closing the question while it has one good answer and not a zillon others...

Answer (score 4):

`^` is an *exclusive* OR, but Python doesn't have a logical exclusive OR. This code  takes advantage of the fact that `True == 1` and `False == 0` so that using the bit-wise exclusive-or has the same effect. (For example, `True ^ False == 1 ^ 0 == 1 == True`.)

Using regular short-circuiting `and` and `or`, then test (with redundant parentheses) would look like

```
sign = -1 if (dividend < 0 and divisor > 0) or (dividend > 0 and divisor < 0) else 1
```

Comment: logical exclusive or is useless anyway since you need to evaluate both parts and that would not short circuit.

Comment: I didn't say exclusive-or would short-circuit; I just referred to `and` and `or` as short-circuiting (rather than Boolean, since strictly speaking they aren't Boolean operators).

Comment: no problem with your answer. I was just noting that it was useless to have `xor` since it would be the same thing as `^`. Well, c++11 has `and` and `&&`, that said...

Answer (score -1):

That is a bitwise XOR operator. See [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/bitwise_operators_example.htm) for more about XORs.

Answer (score -1):

It works because this is not a bitwise OR operator, but rather a bitwise XOR operator. Check out the [Python documentation on bitwise operators](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or):

> Exclusive or or exclusive disjunction is a logical operation that outputs true only when inputs differ (one is true, the other is false).